# Adwords - Some Products are not Valid error on homepage

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

i am trying to audit a few old tags on the website. We have Google Adwords (Remarketing tag ) implemented. When i navigate the site using google tag assistant, i can see that the tag fails on our homepage with the following error : some products are not valid" which does not make sense since we are passing only ecomm_pagetype="home" parameters within the request. Can i ignore this error on all pages besides product pages?

i've attached a few screenshots as well.

[Error in tag assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epCGd.png)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore that. Google tag assistant has a lot of known issues like this.

Other solution would be to pass the ids of all products on main page if any are shown.